# Attempt to invoke virtual method TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) on a null object reference

Tags: android

M a newbie in android, please lend me some help.

Here is my code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.creativehomos.fragments.books;
import com.creativehomos.fragments.interaction;
import com.creativehomos.fragments.portfolio;
import com.creativehomos.fragments.team;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class after_login extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_login);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    initViewPager();
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void initViewPager() {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFrag(new books(), "Books");
    adapter.addFrag(new portfolio(), "Portfolio");
    adapter.addFrag(new interaction(), "Interaction");
    adapter.addFrag(new team(), "Team");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

}
```

everytime I try to run the activity it always gives an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.creativehomos.projectb/com.creativehomos.projectb.after_login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.creativehomos.projectb.after_login.onCreate(after_login.java:32)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

i searched for the problem, and was unable to find the solution, but yes the problem is that the cause of the problem is tabLayout and not the viewPager.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: error point to which line?

Comment: `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` @Tony  this is the error line

Comment: remove this   `tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);`

Comment: then how will i link the tabs in layout and the tabLayout in java file?? @Tony

Answer (score 0):

the tabLayout is empty now you have to add some tabs.

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon("your drawable icon"))
```

for more see the link:
[TabLayout on Android developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout)